# Angular Routes- force reload/new data in dynamic URL

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

When I click a "product" in my app, it uses the URL (#/product/123) to identify the product.

I then use a .split function to tell the API where to pull the individual product detail from.

It loads the first items' data, and that data does not change until I refresh my browser. It's like it thinks every /product/# is the same page.

Can I force it to reload the product page for routes? Maybe there's a better solution too.

Part of my routes:

```
        .state('product', {
            url: '/product/:id',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/components/product/product.html',
                    controller : 'productsCtrl',
                    controllerAs : 'pro',
                    resolve : {
                        products : function productDetailsResolve ($stateParams, productsApi, $log) {
                            return productsApi.getApiData($stateParams.id)
                                .then(function (result) {
                                    return result.data;
                                })
                                .catch(function (err) {
                                    $log.error(err);
                                });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

The JS for the "product" page:

```
.factory('productsApi', ['$http', '$location',
    function($http, $location){
        var BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/api/item/';
        var getApiData = function(product_id) {
            return $http.get(BASE_URL + product_id);
        };
        return {
            getApiData: getApiData
        };
    }]
)

.controller('productsCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', 'productsApi', 'UserService', 'products',
    function($scope, $log, productsApi, UserService, products) {
        var self = this;
        self.products = products;

        $scope.isVisible = function(name){
            return true;// return false to hide this artist's albums
        };

        // <======  Rewrite with accounts preferences
        productsApi.getApiData()
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result.data)) //Shows log of API incoming
                $scope.products = result.data;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                $log.error(err);
            });
    }
]);
```

Product HTML page:

```
<ion-view name="product" hide-nav-bar="true">
    <ion-pane ng-controller="productsCtrl">

        <!--<ion-pane ng-controller="storesCtrl">-->


        <ion-content>

<div class="-""slidebox">

            <ion-slide-box show-pager="true" auto-play="true" does-continue="true">
                <!--<ion-slide ng-repeat="wardrobe in wardrobes">-->
                    <img style="width:100%" src="{{products.image}}">
                </ion-slide>
            </ion-slide-box>
            <div class="customback">
                <i class="ion-chevron-down" native-ui-sref="cards" native-ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}" native-options="{type: 'slide', direction:'down'}">
                </i>
            </div>
            </div>
            <center>
                    <h1>{{products.name}}</h1>
                    <br>
                    <P>${{products.price}}</p>
                    <br>
                    {{products.description}}</b>
        </ion-content>
```

Comment: Few questions to you to understand your issue clearly..1) state ``product`` is used to show the product details with respect to id in the URL and it still shows the old data when id is changed in URL ?? 2) where you are including ``productsCtrl`` ??. If possible then can you provide fiddle or plunker link for this issue.

Comment: Correct- it shows OLD data even when the id in the URL has changed. I am including the productsCtrl in my html (will upload that above). I cannot provide a plunker unfortunately.

Comment: Then best way would be use ``resolves`` in ui-router . Will post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. `ui-router` , `controller` and `factory` code are in same js file now. If you are going put the code in different files then include those js files in index.html.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"]);
 myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('product', {
        url: "/product/:id",
        templateUrl: "products.html",
        controller : 'productsCtrl',
        controllerAs : 'pro',
        resolve : {
            products : function productDetailsResolve ($stateParams, productsApi, $log) {
                    return productsApi.getApiData($stateParams.id)
                        .then(function (result) {
                            return result.data;
                        })
                        .catch(function (err) {
                            $log.error(err);
                        });
                }
        }
    })
});
myapp.factory('productsApi', ['$http', '$location',
function($http, $location){
    var BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/api/item/';
    var getApiData = function(product_id) {
        return $http.get(BASE_URL + product_id);
    };
    return {
        getApiData: getApiData
    };
}]);
myapp.controller('productsCtrl', ['$scope', 'products',function($scope, products) {
          var self = this;
          self.products = products             
          // add rest of the controller code here
}]);
```

Now you access the data in view simpley by `{{pro.products}}`

Comment: Please explain what you mean by accessing the product details in view using pro.products. Also, I cannot get the controller working in my example. I have posted it in my question above.

Comment: ``pro`` is alias name for controller ``productsCtrl`` mentioned in ``ui-router`` state. You can give any name you want. The resolved data ``products`` in ``ui-router`` is passed to ``productsCtrl`` and assigned ``self.products``. So to access this controller data   in view , used 'pro.products'.

Comment: ``cannot get the controller working`` means?? what issue are you getting ??

Comment: Probably syntax. See above code in question. Also, if I am not using productsCtrl, should I use "pro" as my ng-controller for my HTML?

Comment: Controller resolve will crash when getApiData fails because $log is undefined

Comment: Thanks @iH8 for info. I have injected ``$log`` to resolve.

Comment: @Ycon, I did not get your question. As i said ``pro`` is alias name for controllers.  You cant use these alias names if they are not tagged to any controllers. The code in your question has ``productsCtrl`` , so i used the same controller.

Comment: Ok. I have got your code in, but it tells me "Unknown provider: productsProvider <- products <- productsCtrl"

Comment: Ui-router is not getting the controller it seems. trying to run it locally.

Comment: It is running locally. The use of the controller alias- is it necessary or just to help me organize?

Comment: Ok I just updated my answer with working code.  controller alias is not necessary, it just helps us recognize from which controller data is coming when we have more controllers.  If you dont want, then in you controller you need assign the data from resolve to ``$scope`` i think

Comment: Thanks, but your code still says "Unknown provider: productsProvider <- products <- productsCtrl". I have pasted my exact code in the my question above. The "GET" URL is also not working (it doesnt find the product_id).

Comment: is there need to run ``productsApi.getApiData`` in controller again ?? This code is added in resolve. And also no need of ``ng-controller="productsCtrl"`` in view as controller is already mentioned ui-router state.

Comment: I have removed productsCtrl as an ng-controller of my products.html- but still it is not working. The page comes up, but is empty. My $http is not receiving any product_id

Comment: As i saw in your question , you are calling ``getApiData`` service function in resolve and also in controller. In Controller no parameter is passed , so may be you are not getting product_id.  What is the need to call ``getApiData`` in controller.  Please provide fiddle or plunker link which will help to debug.